# Java samples for GraphX

Tags: apache-spark

Where can I find the equivalent of the [GraphX example](http://spark.apache.org/docs/0.9.0/graphx-programming-guide.html#examples) in Java ? For example how does the following translates:

```
val users: RDD[(VertexId, (String, String))] =
sc.parallelize(Array((3L, ("rxin", "student")), (7L, ("jgonzal", "postdoc")),(5L, ("franklin", "prof")), (2L, ("istoica", "prof"))))

// Create an RDD for edges
val relationships: RDD[Edge[String]] = sc.parallelize(Array(Edge(3L, 7L, "collab"),    Edge(5L, 3L, "advisor"), Edge(2L, 5L, "colleague"), Edge(5L, 7L, "pi")))

// Define a default user in case there are relationship with missing user 
val defaultUser = ("John Doe", "Missing")

// Build the initial Graph
val graph = Graph(users, relationships, defaultUser)
```

Comment: Got a response on dev@spark.apache.org:

    **> There is no Java API yet.**

Comment: It'd be nice to answer your own question with this, and provide a link to the discussion page so we can stay updated as well...

Answer (score 1):

Got a response on dev@spark.apache.org: > There is no Java API yet.

[users mailing list](http://apache-spark-developers-list.1001551.n3.nabble.com/graphx-samples-in-Java-td6018.html#a6023)

Answer (score 1):

Still there is no API available for Java:
"GraphX is only available from the Scala API."

Source: https://forums.databricks.com/questions/3185/i-am-looking-for-some-tutorial-on-graphx-using-jav.html

Comment: Yah -marked as Resolved \ Workaround  in https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3665

Answer (score 1):

GraphX is available only in Scala. You can have a look at Graphframe, where they are looking for Dataframes,( Java, Python, Scala)-- instead of low-level RDD. It has few more advantages as it can make use of query optimizer Catalyst, Tungsten project optimization.

You can  convert GraphX TO Graphframes and vice versa. VertexIds are of any type, unlike GraphX only Long. Return type is Dataframe or Graphframe but in GraphX only Graph[VD,ED], RDD.

Answer (score 1):

You can use it like this：

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {


        SparkSession spark = SparkSession
                .builder()
                .appName("javaGraphx")
                .getOrCreate();

        List<Tuple2<Object, Data>> vectorList = Arrays.asList(
                new Tuple2[]{
                        new Tuple2(1L, new Data("A", 1)),
                        new Tuple2(2L, new Data("B", 1)),
                        new Tuple2(3L, new Data("C", 1))}
        );

        JavaRDD<Tuple2<Object, Data>> users = spark.sparkContext().parallelize(
                JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(vectorList.iterator()).asScala()
                        .toSeq(), 1, scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Tuple2.class)
        ).toJavaRDD();

        List<Edge<Integer>> edgeList = Arrays.asList(
                new Edge[]{
                        new Edge(1L, 2L, 1),
                        new Edge(2L, 3L, 1)});

        JavaRDD<Edge<Integer>> followers = spark.sparkContext().parallelize(
                JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(edgeList.iterator()).asScala()
                        .toSeq(), 1, scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Edge.class)
        ).toJavaRDD();

        // construct graph
        Graph<OddRange, Integer> followerGraph =
                GraphImpl
                        .apply(
                                users.rdd(),
                                followers.rdd(),
                                new Data("OVER", 0),
                                StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK(),
                                StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK(),
                                scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Data.class),
                                scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class)
                            );
//If you wanna use pregel, you can use it like this.
        Graph<OddRange, Integer> dd = Pregel.apply(followerGraph,
                new Data("", 0),
                5,
                EdgeDirection.Out(),
                new Vprog(),
                new SendMsg(),
                new MergemMsg(),
                scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(OddRange.class),
                scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(Integer.class),
                scala.reflect.ClassTag$.MODULE$.apply(OddRange.class)
        );

        RDD<OddRange> r = dd
                .vertices()
                .toJavaRDD()
                .map(t->t._2)
                .rdd();

        r.toJavaRDD().foreach(
                o->{
                    System.out.println(o.getS());
                }
                );
    }

//If you wanna use pregel, you can use it like this.
    static class Vprog extends AbstractFunction3< Object, Data, Data, Data> implements Serializable {
        @Override
        public Data apply(Object l, Data self, Data sumOdd) {
            System.out.println(l + "---" + self.getS()+self.getI()+" ---> "+sumOdd.getS()+sumOdd.getI());
                self.setS(sumOdd.getS() + self.getS());
                self.setI(self.getI() + sumOdd.getI());
            System.out.println(l + "---" + self.getS()+self.getI()+" ---> "+sumOdd.getS()+sumOdd.getI());
                //Don't just return self here, return a new one;
                return new Data(self.getS(), self.getI());
        }
    }

    static class SendMsg extends AbstractFunction1<EdgeTriplet<Data,Integer>, scala.collection.Iterator<Tuple2<Object, Data>>> implements Serializable {
        @Override
        public scala.collection.Iterator<Tuple2<Object, Data>> apply(EdgeTriplet<Data,Integer> t) {
            System.out.println(t.srcId()+" ---> "+t.dstId()+" with: "+t.srcAttr().getS()+t.srcAttr().getI()+" ---> "+t.dstAttr().getS()+t.dstAttr().getI());

            if(t.srcAttr().getI() <= 8){
                List<Tuple2<Object, Data>> data = new ArrayList();
                data.add(new Tuple2<>( t.dstId(), new Data(t.srcAttr().getS(), t.srcAttr().getI())));
                return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(data.iterator()).asScala();
            }else{
                return JavaConverters.asScalaIteratorConverter(new ArrayList<Tuple2<Object, Data>>().iterator()).asScala();
            }
        }
    }

    static class MergemMsg extends AbstractFunction2< Data, Data, Data> implements Serializable {
        @Override
        public Data apply(Data a, Data b) {
            return new Data( "" + a.getS() + b.getS(), a.getI() + b.getI());
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

According to [[SPARK-3665] Java API for GraphX - ASF JIRA](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-3665): "Target Version/s: 1.3.0"

Answer (score 0):

Although there is no official or non-official documentation but there is `graphx library for Java`. Check [this](https://mvnrepository.com/search?q=graphx) and [this](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/java/).